# css precedence ambiguity

Tags: css, operator-precedence

I have following css rules:

```
input[type="submit"],input[type="reset"]{
    background-image:url(skins/images/bg_mega_hdr_on.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#submit-search{
    background-image:url(skins/images/bg_blue.png) !important;
}
```

Now according to css rule, id selector has higher precedence over the generic selector then
why is it that, when I apply this rule, the second one is overridden by first one? note that i have even applied !important, then also first one is only applied.

Comment: Are you sure your image URL is correct and that the element has that ID?

Comment: Definitely something wrong with your markup, `!important` overrides everything. Could you http://jsfiddle.net this up with markup included?

Comment: yes, I am sure about that. I have cross checked with chrome inspect element.

Comment: sorry, I figured it out. there was another stylesheet that was causing the problem, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

something like this id="submit-search " **notice the space** can cause odd selector behaviors !
ps . cant comment yet , to little points ...

Answer (score 0):

Works correct for me. See this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fr4Vy/1/). There must be something else wrong (I removed `!important` and it still works fine).